# Drop postgresql database a través de linea de comandos

Tags: postgresql

Estoy intentando eliminar una base de datos en postgres, sin embargo al momento de hacer:

```
DROP DATABASE "MyDatabase";
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

> database MyDatabase is being accessed by other users.

**¿Qué podría hacer para corregir esta situación?**

Comment: Ingresar como administrador ejem: sudo su - postgres
Listar las bases de datos instaladas
psql -l
Eliminar la base 'database'
dropdb 'database';

Comment: Yo tuve el mismo error pero lo solucione cerrando pgadmin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo primero que se puede hacer es:

Revisar que tipo de actividad esta usando la base de datos a eliminar, incluyendo todos los procesos idle, esto se puede hacer con la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname='MyDatabase'; --reemplazar MyDatabase con el nombre de la base de datos con problemas
```

Un vez chequeados estos procesos, si ninguno es critico, se puede terminar el acceso de los mismos a la base de datos con la siguiente consulta:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='MyDatabase';
```

Para postgresql 9.2 o superior

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='MyDatabase'; --reemplazar MyDatabase con el nombre de la base de datos con problemas
```

Luego de esto se puede eliminar la base de datos sin problemas usando:

```
DROP DATABASE "MyDatabase";
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes ejecutar el comando `dropdb` desde la línea de comandos:

```
dropdb 'MyDatabase'
```

Ten en cuenta que tienes que ser un superusuario o el propietario de la base de datos para poder ejecutarlo.

También puedes consultar la vista en `pg_stat_activity` para ver qué tipo de actividad se está llevando a cabo en contra de su base de datos, incluyendo todos los procesos inactivos.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname='MyDatabase';
```

Si no te permite porque hay conexiones activas realiza lo siguiente.

- Finalizar el proceso:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='MyDatabase';
```

- Reemplazar `procid` con `pid`:

```
DROP DATABASE "MyDatabase";
```